# I can't sort a column descending ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to sort the ***PROMEDIOCAL*** field in descending order but when implementing the sort it doesn't work. It lists me correctly by ID and I can also search by DISTRICT but I cannot sort the ***PROMEDIOCAL*** field in descending order when clicking on the header in the table
Controller:

```
public ActionResult ListarProfxServicio(int id, string CadenaBusqueda, string Orden)
 {
        List<TB_Profesionales> lista = new List<TB_Profesionales>();
            ViewBag.cal = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Orden) ? "cod_asc" : "";
            var data = from c in db.TB_Profesionales where c.IDSERVICIO == id select new {c.IDUSUARIO, c.NOMBRE, c.APELLIDO, c.SEXO, c.DISTRITO, c.DESCRIPCIÓN, c.PROMEDIOCAL};
            var data2 = from c in db.TB_Profesionales select c;
            foreach (var pro in data)
            {
                TB_Profesionales p = new TB_Profesionales();
                p.IDUSUARIO = pro.IDUSUARIO;
                p.NOMBRE = pro.NOMBRE;
                p.APELLIDO = pro.APELLIDO;
                p.SEXO = pro.SEXO;
                p.DISTRITO = pro.DISTRITO;
                p.DESCRIPCIÓN = pro.DESCRIPCIÓN;
                p.PROMEDIOCAL = pro.PROMEDIOCAL;
                lista.Add(p);

            }

            switch (Orden)
            {
                case "cod_asc":
                    data = data.OrderByDescending(s => s.PROMEDIOCAL);
                    break;
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CadenaBusqueda))
            {
                data2 = data2.Where(s => s.DISTRITO.ToUpper().Contains(CadenaBusqueda.ToUpper()));
                return View(data2.ToList());
            }
            return View(lista.ToList());
        }
```

View:

```
<th>
   @Html.ActionLink("Cod", "ListarProfxServicio", new {Orden = ViewBag.cal })
</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

You are performing sorting in `data` but you are returning `lista` to the View. So your `lista` is never been sorted.

```cs
public ActionResult ListarProfxServicio(int id, string CadenaBusqueda, string Orden)
{
    List<TB_Profesionales> lista = new List<TB_Profesionales>();

    var data = from c in db.TB_Profesionales where c.IDSERVICIO == id select new {c.IDUSUARIO, c.NOMBRE, c.APELLIDO, c.SEXO, c.DISTRITO, c.DESCRIPCIÓN, c.PROMEDIOCAL};

    ...

    foreach (var pro in data)
    {
        ...

        lista.Add(p);
    }

    switch (Orden)
    {
        case "cod_asc":
            data = data.OrderByDescending(s => s.PROMEDIOCAL);
            break;
    }

    ...

    return View(lista.ToList());
}
```

---

**Solution**

Change the below part to sort for `lista`.

```cs
switch (Orden)
{
    case "cod_asc":
        lista = lista.OrderByDescending(s => s.PROMEDIOCAL);
        break;
}
```

---

**Recommendation**

The `data` and `foreach` part can be refactored together as:

```cs
List<TB_Profesionales> lista = from c in db.TB_Profesionales 
    where c.IDSERVICIO == id 
    select new TB_Profesionales 
    {
        IDUSUARIO  = c.IDUSUARIO, 
        NOMBRE = c.NOMBRE, 
        APELLIDO = c.APELLIDO, 
        SEXO = c.SEXO, 
        DISTRITO = c.DISTRITO, 
        DESCRIPCIÓN = c.DESCRIPCIÓN, 
        PROMEDIOCAL = c.PROMEDIOCAL
    };
```